# Unable to identify

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver

Below is the html for the element i m trying to identify

```
<div class="col-x1"> ==$0
    
        "U Derry
                " ==$0
        </div>
    </div>
```

For the text 'nh' I am able to identify it using below xpath:

```
//strong[(text(),'bb')]
```

Comment: Can you provide a link to this page?

Comment: It's possible that those double quotes need to be taken literally.  Try this: `'//div[contains(text(),"User_123 IFO Derry")]'`

Comment: @JD2775 It's possible. But if he cannot find it in a browser, then somewhere is a typo.

Comment: I guess User_123 is autogenerated, right? Then you should use //div[contains(text(),"IFO Derry")]

Comment: @vitaliis.  Yep, you are right.  If its auto-generated your solution is better.  Let's see what the OP says.  Having a URL would be helpful :)

Comment: The best solution would be the xpath that contains `User` and `IFO Derry`, without auto-generated numbers

Comment: To identify the parent element try this `//div[strong[text()='Access']]`

Answer (score 0):

Try with normalize-space,

//div[normalize-space(text()),'User_123 IFO Derry       ']

Answer (score 0):

You can try using the below x-path. It is working for me in similar instances.

```
"//div[contains(.,'User_123 IFO Derry')]"
```